# Cannot connect to localhost SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, localhost

I just installed SQL Server 2005 SP2 on Vista and am attempting to connect to my object explorer in Management Studio.  When doing so I get the following error:

> Cannot connect to localhost.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: 2)

I am using the following credentials:

```
Server type: Database Engine; Server name: localhost; Authentication: Windows Authentication
```

I am just using SQL Server for a local application. I have tried using 127.0.0.1, my comp name, "." and localhost. I have searched and tried every relevant help topic I could find.  I have reinstalled, turned on IIS (just a guess), updated to latest service packs all around, run as admin, etc.

What am I missing here?

JJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not using express.  It turns out I had a "client" version of SQL Server installed.  I didn't even know there was a client version.  I ran the full install and added the sa user as Windows Authentication wasn't working for me (next goal).  I am connecting via "localhost" (just localhost), so I don't fully understand what the instance suggestion was all about.

Basically the solution was to get the full version installed.  My bad.  Easy fix.

JJ

Answer (score 1):

Did you run the User Provisioning Tool for Vista? See [KB929907  You may be unable to perform most database operations after you log on to an instance of SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Service Pack 1 on a Windows Vista-based computer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929907)

Comment: I have SP2 installed.  I am thinking that the provisioning tool is already there.

Comment: Yes, is there, but did you *run* it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `(local)`

Also if you have an instance name you can try `myComputerName\instanceName`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the instance name. You don't just connect to `localhost`, but to any of the following (assuming that your machine is called `dago` and your instance `sqlexpress`):

```
localhost\sqlexpress
dago\sqlexpress
.\sqlexpress
```

Comment: Not every sql server instance is a named instance.  For a default instance, you don't use the syntax you're referring to.

Comment: Now I remember. (Don't currently have access to a version other than Express.) Thanks!